# Can PXFormula aggregate non-bound fields

Tags: acumatica

I have a header and detail user field of type decimal.  Both are not bound to the Db.  The value of detail user field is set during RowSelected event.  My goal is to accumulate the user field values in the details cache, and assign the value to the header field.  Both user fields are defined in cache extensions.

I see PXFormula defines RowSelecting event handler to calculate values for unbound DAC fields.  So I define the PXParent & the PXFormula in the child DAC.  T200 recommends to add the PXParent in the first FK field.  But I defined a cache extension, so a different user field is used.

Unfortunately the header field still displays zero, even though detail field has values.  Is this not possible when using non-bound user fields?

Comment: Have you tried PXUnboundFormula in place of PXFormula?

Answer (score 0):

Chris, PXFormula (same applies to PXUnboundFormula) has never supported aggregates for unbound header fields. You can still use PXFormula to handle changes the user makes in UI, but this will still require use of a RowSelecting handler from your side to calculate aggregated unbound header fields when record is retrieved from DB.

Comment: I notice that when I assign the header field, during Detail_RowSelected event, the value remains null.  This happens when the detail field contains any value.